# PHP Array with soap

Tags: php, soap

I am calling a soap webservice which works.

```
$client = new nusoap_client('https://site/webservices/Customer.asmx?WSDL', 'wsdl');
  $param = array('asWebSecurityKey' => $asWebSecurityKey,'asEmail' => $user,'asPassword' => $pass);
  $result = $client->call('AuthenticateCustomer', array('parameters' => $param), '', '', false, true);
```

After I call the service I receive an array like this but not sure how to use them on a php page any help?

```
Array
(
    [AuthenticateCustomerResult] => 0
    [aCustomerArray] => Array
        (
            [UDT_Cpower_CustomerInfo] => Array
                (
                    [CustomerKey] => 57f8cb38-08e9-428a-8f7d-808941b92106
                    [Title] => 
                    [FirstName] => TestMe
                    [LastName] => TestMe
                    [FullName] => TestMe TestMe
                    [Company] => 
                    [Address_Street] => 45 Test Rd.
                    [Address_Street2] => 
                    [Address_City] => Toronto
                    [Address_ProvState] => HI
                    [Address_PostalZip] => h0h k0k
                    [Phone_Home] => (444) 686-2222
                    [Phone_Work] => (333) 686-2222
                    [Phone_Other] => 
                    [Email] => test@test.com
                    [Language] => 
                )

        )

)
```

I have tried the following:

```
$CustomerKey = ($result['CustomerKey']);
$FullName = ($result['FullName']);
$Address_Street = ($result['Address_Street']);
$Address_ProvState = ($result['Address_ProvState']);
$Address_PostalZip = ($result['Address_PostalZip']);
$Phone_Home = ($result['Phone_Home']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a multi-dimensional array structure here. There are 2 levels of nesting. `AuthenticateCustomerResult` is a scalar value `0`, but `aCustomerArray` is itself an array with one element whose key is called `UDT_Cpower_CustomerInfo`. It's in there you'll find all the properties you want.

For example:

```
// Assuming $result is the outermost Array structure you posted above.
$CustomerKey = $result['aCustomerArray']['UDT_Cpoiwer_CustomerInfo']['CustomerKey'];
```

Or to save some typing, refer to that sub-array with a variable:

```
// Make $custinfo point directly to the nested array
$custinfo = $result['aCustomerArray']['UDT_Cpoiwer_CustomerInfo'];
// Then you can access those values from $custinfo
$CustomerKey = $custinfo['CustomerKey'];
$FullName = $custinfo['FullName'];
```

But really, I would not bother with creating variables like `$CustomerKey, $FullName` for each of those. It adds a lot of unnecessary variables to your global namespace. Instead I would just use them directly from `$custinfo` as created above. Since the values are related, it makes good logical sense to keep their relationship by preserving them as an array.

```
echo "The customer's key is {$custinfo['CustomerKey']} and name is {$custinfo['FullName']}.";
```